# root access to GlusterFS volume with root-squash

Tags: linux, root, glusterfs

I want to export my glusterfs volume with the option `server.root-squash` enabled, so that clients (over which I have no control)  can't perform actions as root on the volume.

However I, as and admin, would like to still be able to access files as root (at least from a server), so that I can, for example, change permissions and run rsync.

With NFS, if I enable root-squash, I can still log into the server and perform actions as root from there.

How can I obtain the same result with gluster?